# How to split a line into multiple lines?

Tags: powershell, csv, split

I have a CSV file which looks something like this:

```
Column1,Column2,Column3
John,Smith,"AA, AH, CA, NI, PB"
Reginald,Higginsworth,"AA, AH, CA, NI, PB, SN, ZS"
```

You'll notice that there are multiple values within `Column3` (enclosed in the quotes).
What I need to do is produce a line of data in the CSV for each of these values in `Column3`, i.e. the file would need to look something like:

```
Column1,Column2,Column3
John,Smith,AA
John,Smith,AH
John,Smith,CA
John,Smith,NI
John,Smith,PB
Reginald,Higginsworth,AA
Reginald,Higginsworth,AH
Reginald,Higginsworth,CA
Reginald,Higginsworth,NI
Reginald,Higginsworth,PB
Reginald,Higginsworth,SN
Reginald,Higginsworth,ZS
```

I have had more than several attempts at this and can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Next time please include a description of what you have tried, and how that failed to produce the desired result. Without that your question is basically asking "write code for me", which easily leads to downvotes.

Comment: Ah ok thanks for the advice. I will edit my post and add my attempt!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Import-Csv` to read the input file, then split the third column and create new output lines for each resulting element:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\input.csv' | ForEach-Object {
  foreach ($value in ($_.Column3 -split ', ')) {
    $_ | Select-Object -Exclude Column3 -Property *,@{n='Column3';e={$value}}
  }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

The `Select-Object` construct replaces the existing property `Column3` with a new property `Column3` that contains only a single value.